regex - find any block between curly brackets that contains one or more non-numeric characters
I want to find in a text all ocurrences of blocks between curly brackets, that contains any non-numeric character.
For example, in the text:
something {34dj 4s} and something else {335} and more {dgw} and {6} or whatever

it should match 2 items: {34dj 4s} and {dgw}
I have tried with this (im using it in .net c#) but it will match only ocurrences that ONLY contains non-numeric characters...:
@"{[^0-9]*}"


You may use this regex to match {...} with at least one non-digit in between:
\{[0-9]*[^0-9}][^}]*}

RegEx Demo
RegEx Details:

\{: Match {
[0-9]*: Match 0 or more digits
[^0-9}]: Match a non-digit
[^}]*: Match 0 or more of any character that is not }
}: Match }


Other possibility: {(?>[0-9]*)[^}]+}

Thanks @CasimiretHippolyte and I believe {[0-9]*+[^}]+} would be a bit speedier
